# Creating a new directory from C# with Encrypting File System switched on

Tags: c#, windows, encrypting-file-system

Has anyone created a new directory from C# with Encrypting File System switched on?

Additionally any information on doing this from an install would be helpful too.

Answer (score 7):

Creating an encrypted directory would be a two step process - create it using Directory.CreateDirectory and then encrypt it using the Win32 function EncryptFile. Sample code -

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EncryptDir
{
    public class Sample
    {
        DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool EncryptFile(string filename);

        public static void Main ()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("MyEncryptedDirectory");
            EncryptFile("MyEncryptedDirectory");
        }
}
```

References:

[EncryptFile Function @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364021(v=VS.85).aspx)

[Handling encrypted files and directories @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365005(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: That's great! Many thanks for this.
It's odd that there doesn't seem to be a way to do it just within the .Net class libraries.

Comment: You are welcome! Its often the case that native .net libraries lag Win32 APIs; I wish it were the other way around now!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that calling [File.EncryptFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt.aspx) also works on directories. I guess it just forwards to `EncryptFile` internally.

Answer (score 1):

The managed methods [`File.Encrypt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_Encrypt_System_String_) and [`FileInfo.Encrypt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.encrypt?view=netframework-4.7.1) both simply call the native `EncryptFile()` that is shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472649).

So, no need to go to all the trouble to declare the p/invoke API. Just use the built-in methods.